# Singleton or Static class or neither?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a Windows Form application that is basically a recreation of paint. I have a toolstrip of various buttons, I am able to drag a copy of a bitmap onto the diagram and place it on the drawing panel. However I want to add the functionality of being able to move the bitmap around the panel and re-size it using the 9 nodes on the corners and middle of lines.

Currently my form has a

```
    List<Diagram> theDiagrams;
```

which contains a list of custom diagram objects. Each diagram represents the bitmap on the drawing panel, it has the coordinates, size, z-index, bitmap, and a bit of other info. However now I want only the Diagram with the focus to be able to be editable, or to have those 9 nodes around the outside with the ability to move/re-size it. I'm thinking of creating a class that is a derivation of the Diagram class I currently have however I only want to be able to create 1 of them. Should I create a static class or possibly use a singleton design pattern to ensure only one of those objects can be created at a time. Ideally I'd like this class to be null from the start and only get set to a copy of a diagram when it's necessary.

I'm more less trying to figure out how to design the class for this particular scenario so I don't think much code is needed to get the gist of what I'm saying. However if you feel you need some examples of what I'm talking about, I'm more than happy to share the code to ensure I come up with the best solution possible.

If you didn't understand my question, should I use a singleton design pattern, a static class, or neither for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid static and singleton patterns in this case. What if you have more than 1 form (MDI application)

The selected bitmap/layer is something like a property of your image/form, no module or class may alter it directly. Your image class is in control of the `List<Diagram>`

---

I think you should have a `private Diagram selectedDiagram;` field that contains the current selected diagram defined in the same control/form that contains `List<Diagram> theDiagrams` field.

When drawing the complete list, you should skip the selected one and paint this as the last diagram. (so it would be topmost)

Just an idea....

**PSEUDO**

```
private void UpdateBitmap()
{
    foreach(var diagram in theDiagrams)
    {
        if(diagram == selectedDiagram)
            continue;

        // draw
    }

    if(selectedDiagram != null)
    {
        // draw with corner nodes and/or other helper controls (z-top)

        // does the corner nodes and/or other helper controls exists?
        if(!areEditControlsCreated)
             CreateEditControls();

    }
    else
    {
        if(areEditControlsCreated)
             DestroyEditControls();

    }
}
```

and when you deselect a diagram, just clear the `selectDiagram = null;` field and repaint the bitmaps.